# What's difference between WRKACTJOB and WRKJOB with status active in AS400?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I'd like to watch the status of a job, sometimes I can find the job with command WRKACTJOB or WRKJOB. But, sometimes, I can only find it in WRKJOB with status active. Why didn't show up in WRKACTJOB since it is acttive?

Comment: WRKJOB doesn't select by status "active" or otherwise. It only cares if a named job exists or not. WRKACTJOB **only** reports on status "active" jobs. However, numerous "active" jobs are excluded from the WRKACTJOB list unless explicitly requested to be included with F14=Include|Exclude.

Answer (score 2):

try command wrkactjob job(*job name*) to check the particular job status if it is running. unless you are not submitting the job to same subsystem you might not find the job always at same place from wrkactjob. hope this answers :)

Answer (score 1):

WRKACTJOB shows the current jobs running on the system. If a job runs through fast, you might never see it. It helps to watch the subsystem of where the job will run (prompt WRKACTJOB and you can specify the subsystem). Also make sure you refreshing with F10 instead of F5. F10 restarts the data collection, whereas F5 typically refreshes the data already collected.

[WRKACTJOB](https://as400i.com/2019/11/14/wrkactjob/)

WRKJOB allows you to work with any job that has been run on the system. Typically this is useful to look at the job log or spool file.